# Saving records in Entity Framework using a loop not moving to the next record after a failure

Tags: entity-framework-core, savechanges

I have a list of records that I'm trying to insert into a SQL database using Entity Framework Core.

- Record 1 is Valid
- Record 2 is Not valid (let's say it's a duplicate key violation but it could also be bad data)
- Record 3 is Valid
- Record x is Valid

I'm trying to save the record using a loop. My crud service just adds the record to the `DbSet` and calls `SaveChangesAsync()` (yes, I know I should call `SaveChanges` once or use `AddRange`, but it's split like this at the moment).

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
    var result = await _crud.CreateAsync(record);

    if (result.HasError)
        // log error
}
```

Now, the first record is valid and saves fine.

The 2nd record then causes an error, fine as it's logged.

But, here is the problem. Every record after that fails even though they are valid. The error message received (and data) is the same as record 2. It's as if that record doesn't get removed or cleared from the context.

The crud.CreateAsync method is doing the following:

```
try
{
    await _entity.AddAsync(record);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Result.Success()
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return Result.Fail(ex);
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: *The error message received (and data) is the same as record 2* ?? If all the records after record 2 are exactly the same as record 2 I think the expectation is they will all fail too...

Comment: *It's as if that record doesn't get removed or cleared from the context* ?? why would a call to CreateAsync be expected to remove anything from the context?

Comment: @topsail record 3 is different. But I receive the error from record 2 still! 

So, record 2 fails which is fine but I want to continue saving further records (which are different)

Comment: So it record 2 fails on SaveChanges, should I be doing something to clear the context?

Comment: I don't think its possible to answer without more details. Such as what _crud is doing, and what is the error. Also, you haven't shown any reason why record 3 and other records wouldn't fail (for the same reason as record 2). It is possible the error messages are just what the say they are (despite your assertion that no errors are possible). I don't know what you mean by "clearing the context".

Comment: The Crud service adds the record to the DbSet and then calls SaveChangesAsync on the context, it's at that point it fails.

Comment: Is the crud service properly disposing the context after each request? We still don't see your code...? We still don't even have the error message for clarity...?

Comment: The code you posted is simply wrong. ORMs like EF are far higher abstractions than low-level CRUD classes. No loop is needed. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. `SaveChanges` persists *all* changes in a single transaction, which is why there's no need for loops. `Add` doesn't execute an `INSERT` it starts tracking a new object in the `Added` state. It would be a lot easier if you posted the rest of the code so people can show how EF actually works.

Comment: `here is the problem` that problem is *caused* by the bad loop. `SaveChanges` will persist all changes in a single internal database transaction. Either all objects are saved or none. There's nothing to clean up and retries are actually *easier* - you retry the operation with a new Unit-of-Work instance, ie DbContext.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did write that in my post that I should be calling SaveChanges once!

But doing that, it fails for all records so I get nothing inserted.

The records come from an external source that I don't control but I need to save the valid records. That's the reason I've split it like this for the moment at least anyway.

Comment: @Sun post the original problem and code then. The current problem is *caused* by the split and loop. Your Create may well perform 42 DELETEs and 67 UPDATEs. As for importing data from external applications, that's an ETL job that's just *not* a valid scenario for ORMs. You aren't working with individual application objects but rows, constraints, validations, tables. The typical way to handle this is to perform any validations or transformations in memory and then import the data to a *staging table* before updating the final target table.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what this "_crud" reference is, the issue you are facing is called a poisoned DbContext. You have told EF to add (or update) an entity that is not valid. That entity will remain in the change tracker until you tell the DbContext to ignore it. (Detaching it)

So if your _crud.CreateAsync(record) looks something like:

```
try
{  
    _context.Records.Add(record);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return new SuccessResult(record);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return new FailureResult(ex);
}
```

You need to remove any invalid entity or entities from the DbContext that are poisoning if you want to continue using that DbContext instance. Otherwise your unit of work (lifetime of the DbContext) needs to be shortened to processing each row so that a fresh DbContext instance is used for each insert. That would typically mean passing in a DbContextFactory reference rather than a DbContext instance.

So in the above example to try and de-poison the DbContext:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    context.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Detached;
    return new FailureResult(ex);
}
```

Note that if record includes any child entities that were created/added, those need to be detached as well. Any references to existing entities should not be detached.

Comment: The DbContext isn't poisoned, the question's code is bad. `SaveChanges` commits the unit of work, but the loop treats it as a connection instead. *Maybe* one could call ChangeTracker.Clear to bring the DbContext to the state before the latest iteration but frankly, that's trying to fix the bad code by adding even more code. Detaching the latest object makes some very strong assumptions about what caused the problem - what if there was a pending DELETE too?

Comment: What the OP describes is a poisoning scenario. They have added a bad entity which resulted in an error they handled, then moved on to add another good entity but the `SaveChanges` still tries to commit the bad, tracked entity resulting in the confusion where #3 fails outlining issues still with #2. Changetracker.Clear would likely work though discards all remaining tracked references. I agree that overall it is not a good way to attempt to process data.